# Selenium element request

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm not able to find an element using Selenium library. I've tried by id, by Xpath, nothing... pretty sure is something on the html iframe or framesets, but I've also tried `driver.switch_to.frame` without success. 
I'm a beginner on Python so, appreciate your patience on explanation.

Idea is automatize using a script to input data on the company intranet.

Here is the code I've tried so far and some comments:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\tvalente\PycharmProjects\TESTEs\descriptionCapture\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://quest.slb.com/quest/QuestLogInx.asp?NextRptType=&NextQPID=') #this page is just an automatic login to redirect to another page

time.sleep(7)

driver.get('https://quest.slb.com/quest/IndexIE.asp') #as i dont know to use Selenium very well yet, to make sure im requesting the element on the correct page, i asked the browser to refresh at the redirected page. If there is a way to do it without refreshing the URL, also appreciate the help ! For example, if i click on a link which will redirect to a new page, do i need to use the driver.get('new page URL') again to work on the tags or there is another way ? 

time.sleep(4)

driver.switch_to.frame('navframe') #please see HTLM code below. this is the iframe.  
reportnumber = driver.find_element_by_id('strCriteria') #this is the text field tag id inside the iframe.    
reportnumber.send_keys('testandto') #This is what i want to text before submit
```

Below is the HTML :

Not sure how i can share a image from my computer here...

Comment: You shouldn't be including an image of the HTML anyway. Try editing your post to include the lines of HTML with the elements you want to find.

Comment: Additionally, you need to point Selenium to the iframe before you switch to it. Try `iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="frame_name_here"]')`, then `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`. Additionally, every time the content in the iframe reloads, you'll need to re-find the frame's element using the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether frame is available in your application.

search for "iframe" in your DOM and confirm the element is available inside the frame. 
If it is inside the frame, then you need to switch the control inside the frame and then only you can work on that element.

To Switch inside the frame below is one of the syntax:

driver.switchTo().frame("frameid");

then perform any action on the webelemment.